# Getting timeout when access the 80 port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, azure, networking, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using the new Azure cloud app and I have created a new VM with ubuntu 14.04.

I installed apache2 and some common modules (like php5).

Well, after that, I configured my app, but when I tried to access, The browser shows "Timeout" (using Chrome). The "ping" maps the hostname to the ip address but it doesn't gets any response (i suppose that ping is disabled by default)

At first I thought it was my app, so I only set the default apache settings in the "sites-enabled" folder (the one with the static html page that comes with apache).

But the same happens, so I check the usual things like firewall, iptables rules, etc. But I get always the same result :/

This is not my first server, but I'm not able to think in another option, so I just want to check what you guys think about what could be the problem.

iptables -L -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

ufw status

```
Status: inactive
```

default settings on the site-enabled folder (I erased the comments lines)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

netstat -ntlp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1654/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      34899/postgres
tcp        0      0 x2.x2.x2.x2:16001 (other ip diff from server's ip)   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      937/python
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      48801/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1654/sshd
```

telnet ip 80 (from my pc)

```
Connecting To x.x.x.x 80...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80
: Connect failed
```

telnet localhost 80

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
exit
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Not Implemented</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Implemented</h1>
<p>exit to / not supported.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at x3.x3.x3.x3 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The ip x2.x2.x2.x2 and x3.x3.x3.x3 have the same value but they aren't equal to the server IP. (At least isn't the same ip value I use to connect to the VM by ssh)

Comment: Can you please output the result of "netstat -ntlp" and try to telnet into your VM? (telnet ip 80)

Comment: @Bacon I added the info ;)

Comment: Can you try (I know it's bad) to drop all your iptables rules? (iptables -F) if you don't save them (iptables-save) they'll come back at next boot. Is there any firewall rule that you can set in Azure Cloud?

Comment: In this post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msftashwin/archive/2014/01/28/how-to-setup-and-protect-an-azure-application-with-a-barracuda-firewall-v3.aspx) they say how to open port 80 on the barracuda firewall, but I'm not sure it's related to your setup

Comment: Thanks @Bacon, I already tried flush the ip tables rules, but nothing changes, I dont have any additional firewall on my setup

Comment: Btw, you can ssh to the server right? and I guess from the inside you can ping the outer world (you've setup your system with apt I guess). Also, can you give the output of `traceroute ip` where ip is your VM address?

Comment: @Bacon - there is no barracuda firewall in the OP's case. That's something far more advanced. And by default, there are no iptable rules enabled on the linux images - everything is open.

Comment: I have to confess I don't know well Azure apps, so I'm thinking about everything that could block outside http traffic (which seems to be the case)

Comment: @ClarkJeria - have you configured endpoints yet? Without opening endpoints via Azure VM configuration (you can do that in the portal, CLI, PowerShell, etc.), no traffic will reach the VM from the outside. By default, only one endpoint is configured, for ssh.

Comment: All that said: This is really an infrastructure question, not a programming one, and belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be an endpoint. By default when you create a virtual machine in the Azure portal, endpoints for Remote Desktop, Windows PowerShell Remoting, and Secure Shell (SSH) are automatically created.

You will have to go into the Azure portal to configure additional endpoints.

Each endpoint has a public and private. Public is used for outside requests/traffic coming into the VM through the load balance. Private is use by the VM for incoming traffic to route to the proper port/app.

Here is a link on Azure help that talks about setting up endpoints
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/